# Looping through an array of strings

Tags: c#, combinations

I have an array with letters for example

```
string[] arrayLetters = new string[] {"A","B", "C", "D"}
```

and so on.

Now a user will type in the number of sets he want to display...

if for example he types in 2, then the output would be:

AB,AC,AD, BC, BD

For a set of three, the output would be like:

ABC, ABD, ACD, BCD

... and so on.

Can you please help me solve this little scenario I have?

Thanks
Mark Montebello the Cicco

Comment: In other words, you want to display all combinations of length N where N is entered by the user? This sounds a bit homeworkish, if that's the case, use the `homework` tag.

Comment: Yes, but the letter will be displayed once, and if the current location is B, the letter A won't be displayed

Comment: Please review: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/recipes/Combinatorics.aspx It will help you with your homework.

Answer (score 2):

This [Code Project article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/recipes/Combinatorics.aspx) gives a good overview of combinations (what you are asking), permutations etc and provides a library for calculating them in C#. It's just one of the many libraries that provide this functionality.

BTW combinatorics is introductory computing material. That's why people suspect this may be a school assignment.

Comment: I see.. Thanks I will try it out... but it is not a school assignment.

Comment: Can't the scenario I gave, be done by simple looping, not using any other classes..

Comment: Yes, it can.  But most other examples will be using recursion, which confuses most people even more than classes do.  :)